# How to copy data displayed in summary of any analysis to a dataframe?

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting, arima

I am trying to carry out time series modelling and would like to copy the data input we get from running a data model onto a dataframe. For eg, when I run the following code:

```
a<-auto.arima(tt1[1:33,1])
summary(a)
```

I get the following output, which I want to copy to a dataframe to analyse in future-to see how many instances across different models have I got similar values.

```
Series: tt1[1:33, 1] 
ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
          ma1      mean
      -0.4421  219.4943
s.e.   0.2079   27.2563

sigma^2 estimated as 79580:  log likelihood=-232.1
AIC=470.19   AICc=471.02   BIC=474.68

Training set error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE MPE MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 3.103363 273.4178 233.6786 NaN  Inf 0.6599926 0.07472074
```

Comment: Hi @Akhilnandh Ramesh, welcome to SO!   It is stored in ```a``` already as lists. If you do ```str(a)```, you will see the various lists that can be referenced to access the information.

Comment: `sw_tidy()` in the package [`sweep`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sweep/vignettes/SW00_Introduction_to_sweep.html) may also be useful to place parameters into a (tidy) tibble.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "broom" package to solve this issue. [Check the package vignette for more information](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html). Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(broom)
library(forecast)
library(fpp2) # To get a data set to work on
# Fit a linear regression with AR errors
fit <- Arima(uschange[,"Consumption"], xreg = uschange[,"Income"], order = c(1,0,0))
# Use broom to convert summary output into a data.frame
tidy(fit) # coefficients and standard error
# Get main statistics
glance(fit)
```